# Ball released to a hole on the wall

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, velocity

> A ball thrown from the ground to a hole on the wall (with $h$ as its height). Distance from initial position of the ball to the wall is $d$. The effects of air friction are negligible.

Asked (I've solved some of them):

1. Equation of motion: from $F = m a$ in x and y direction, I got $a_x=0$ and $a_y= -g$
2. Position $x(t)$ and $y(t)$, velocity $v_x(t)$ and $v_y(t)$:

   - $v_x(t) = v_0 .cos \alpha$, then I integrate into $x(t) = v_o .t. cos \alpha$
   - $v_y(t) = v_0 .sin \alpha - g .t$, then I integrate into $y(t)=v_o.t. sin \alpha-{1\over 2}.g.t^2$
3. Initial velocity $v_o$ and initial angle $\alpha$??? which the ball velocity should contain only a horizontal component to get into the hole (not yet done).

I've tried to set $y(t) = h$ which is the height of the hole, then I solved for the t with only positive part. Then I insert my t into $x(t) = v_0 .t .cos \alpha$ equation and also replace x(t) with d which is the horizontal distance. But I'm ended with the equation of:

$d = {v_0^2.sin\alpha .cos\alpha \over g} + {v_0.cos \alpha \over g}\sqrt{v_0^2.sin^2\alpha -2.g.h}$

For problem no. 3, do I just use this equation and solve for $v_0$ and $\alpha$ or is there something else that I missed? Also I'm confused how to change the equation to get the $v_0$ and $\alpha$. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest writing $v_{0x} = v_0 \cos\alpha$ and $v_{0y} = v_0 \sin\alpha$ so you don't have to write $\cos$ and $\sin$ so much. You can then find $v_0$ and $\alpha$ using $v_0 = \sqrt{v_{0x}^2 + v_{0y}^2}$ and $\tan\alpha = \frac{v_{0y}}{v_{0x}}$.

You've already found expressions $v_x(t) = v_{0x}$ and $v_y(t) = v_{0y} - gt$, as well as $x(t) = v_{0x} t$ and $y(t) = v_{0y} t - \frac{g}{2} t^2$.
The aim now is to figure out what $v_{0x}$ and $v_{0y}$ are.
Suppose you define $T$ to be the time when the ball hits the hole. You know that the ball must be at the hole's position at time $T$, that is, $x(T) = d$ and $y(t) = T$. You have these two equations, but three unknowns ($v_{0x}$, $v_{0y}$ and $T$). These are not enough equations to solve the system uniquely (which means that there are many ways of throwing the ball so that it hits the hole if you can vary both the angle and the speed at which you throw it).

So you need a third equation, which you can get from the criterion that there should be only a horizontal velocity component when the ball enters the hole: $v_y(T) = 0$. Now you have three unknowns and a system of three equations

$$ \left\{\begin{aligned} x(T) &= d \\ y(T) &= h \\ v_y(T) &= 0, \end{aligned}\right. \quad\text{or rewritten}\quad
\left\{\begin{aligned} v_{0x} T &= d \\ v_{0y} T - \frac{g}{2} T^2 &= h \\ v_{0y} - gT &= 0. \end{aligned}\right.$$

The rest is just algebra to solve the system of equations. I would suggest that you begin with solving the first and third equations for $v_{0x}$ and $v_{0y}$ and then continue solving the middle one.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. solving T from the 3rd eqn: $T = {v_0sin\alpha \over g}$ and insert it into 2nd eqn: $v_0 = {\sqrt{2gh}\over sin \alpha}$. Then I got $v_{0x} = \sqrt{2gh} arctan \alpha$ and $v_{0y} = \sqrt{2gh}$. So I just write $\alpha = arctan ({v_{0x}\over v_{0y}})$? because if I insert $v_0$ again it will be $tan \alpha$ again... And also to find T, I didn't use 1st eqn because 3rd eqn will minimize some elements of 2nd eqn...

Comment: I think you should avoid using $v_0$ and $\alpha$ until the very end, it confuses things. Knowing both $v_0$ and $\alpha$ is the same as knowing both $v_{0x}$ and $v_{0y}$, so make sure you know them both first. My way of solving this equation system is: Use the first and third equations to find $v_{0x} = d/T$ and $v_{0y} = gT$. Use this in the second equation to get $gT^2 - \frac{g}{2}T^2 = h$, which gives $T = \sqrt{2h/g}$. Substitute back to get $v_{0x} = d\sqrt{g/2h}$ and $v_{0y} = \sqrt{2gh}$. Finally you can find $v_0 = \sqrt{\frac{d^2g}{2h} + 2gh}$ and $\alpha = \arctan{\frac{d}{2h}}$.

Comment: Hopefully you can understand my steps. I encourage you to practice with more problems, because that is the only way to get better at them. Also I would recommend that you spend some time after you solve each problem to go back and see if you can improve your solution or solve it in a different way. Doing that can make you understand the problems and get a feeling for how physics works!

Comment: I changed the $v_{0x}$ and $v_{0y}$ in terms of $v_0$ again, my fault... I don't know how to thank you again... No problem, I understand your explanation. Know that I'm so reckless about this things. And yes, I need more practices & must be very careful when operating those equations :)

Comment: Of course, I'm not saying it is *wrong* to calculate in terms of $v_0$ and $\alpha$. I just think that it is easier not to, because you have to write less. But both ways do work.